# Cannot commit to svn - access denied

Tags: svn, commit

I am working on a small project with SVN.

I checked out the project:

```
svn co http://mylocalserver/projectx/ .
```

I made my changes (updated and added files):

```
svn add file1.php, file2.php
```

But then, every time I want to commit my changes using this command:

```
svn commit -m "added file1.php and file2.php and updated the bug #4123" file1.php file2.php gah.php
```

I get: `Access is denied`

What can be the problem?

Comment: mylocalserver means your computer? or the svn server in your server? or a www svn server?

Comment: it's a local network server (not my computer)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**If you don't use an LDAP server you have to check this:**

In your `/path/to/the/project/conf/svnserve.conf` check if you have something like:

```
anon-access = none
auth-access = none
```

You will have to change to use:

```
anon-access = none
auth-access = write
password-db = /path/to/passwd
```

then in your `/path/to/the/project/conf/passwd`

you can create your users:

```
user1 = password
```

**If you are using an LDAP server please read these articles:**

Maybe your password is expire or you don't have the full rights to commit.

Maybe these articles will help:

[http://directory.fedoraproject.org/wiki/Howto:Subversion_Apache_LDAP](http://directory.fedoraproject.org/wiki/Howto%3aSubversion_Apache_LDAP)

http://www.mylinuxtips.info/?p=7

Answer (score 2):

You should check that

- you have permission to write to the repository (ask the repository admin)
- you committing using the username which was configured. By default Subversion uses the username you are using when issuing the command, but you can specify a different one with the `--username` option

  ```
  svn --username mysvnusername --message "added file1.php and file2.php and updated the bug #4123" file1.php file2.php gah.php
  ```

If you are the repository administrator check the log file of the Subversion Server to see what went wrong