# svn on mac access denied

Tags: svn, homebrew

i'm pretty new to mac and i installed svn using homebrew. However whenever i try to run a svn command like checkout or import, it tells me, that permission to this url is denied(even though i know have access, since all works fine under windows)
When i enter the command it first asks me for authentication. This at least is working(if i enter a wrong password, it asks again for authentication).
Any ideas why it claims that i don't have permission for the repository?
I already tried reinstalling svn

Comment: The macOS use the same linux's command line. So does your user is the system's administrator? You can use sudo before run the command line to checkout or import. Check this link: https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/apps/subversion/configuration/configure-use-svn-repository/.

Answer (score 0):

Check if access rights for your folder(s) are configured wrong, so that an unknown SID is the owner or has read/write permission but not your user account.

Maybe check the file permissions of your local SVN files and make sure that your current user/your TortoiseSVN process has the necessary access rights to change these files.

If you don't use an LDAP server you have to check this:

In your /path/to/the/project/conf/svnserve.conf check if you have something like:

```
anon-access = none
auth-access = none
```

You will have to change to use:

```
anon-access = none
auth-access = write
password-db = /path/to/passwd
```

then in your /path/to/the/project/conf/passwd

you can create your users:

```
user1 = password
```

If you are using an LDAP server please read these articles:

Maybe your password has expired or you don't have the full rights to commit.

Maybe these articles will help:

http://directory.fedoraproject.org/wiki/Howto:Subversion_Apache_LDAP

http://www.mylinuxtips.info/?p=7

Reference:- [Cannot commit to svn - access denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195129/cannot-commit-to-svn-access-denied)

Hopefully, this will resolve your issue, please reach out in the comment section if further clarification is required.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue in the past while using SVG on Mac OS, what works for me is instead of endpoint url, I tried server IP for example in my case

```
http://dxbABC01:81/svn/ABC_XYZ_NAME_PRODUCT/
```

I used IP address in SVN settings, for me I was using webstrom client

```
http://10.20.44.34:81/svn/ABC_XYZ_NAME_PRODUCT/
```